# subproject not compiling Java/Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am trying to add a subproject to my main one in Android Studio. I have it compiling in the build gradle of the whole project. When ever I try to build the project or compile it it gives me out this error.

```
Error:(9, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments [project ':subProject.exude'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\allga\Desktop\behe-keyboard-master\behe-keyboard-master\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

Here is the code for the build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    compile project('subProject.exude')
```

Comment: Show your project structure

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be a solution to your problem. Let's say there are two modules in your project, typically named as `app` and `lib`. Now you want to use `lib` module in your app module. So, you need to add it to your `build.gradle(app module)`.

```
compile project(':lib')
```

Comment: I have tried that but it hasnt changed anything i am still getting the same error.

Comment: According to your question, you have put it in wrong gradle file. Put it inside app module build.gradle, not in project level build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

> I have it compiling in the build gradle of the whole project.

It may imply two cases:

1. You're adding `compile project('subProject.exude')` to your **root**/**project** build.gradle
2. You're adding `compile project('subProject.exude')` to all of your module build.gradle

In first case, you must not add the `compile project` to your root build.gradle. Because it not belong there.

In second case, you're incorrectly adding the classpath to your dependencies block in your module build.gradle. This is incorrect, because you're adding classpath for dependencies:

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
   compile project('subProject.exude')

   ...
}
```

This is corrrect:

```
dependencies {
   compile project('subProject.exude')

   ...
}
```

Module dependencies should not exist in root/project build.gradle.